# "The place where I work." or "The place where I work in."?

Tags: prepositions

"The place where I work." or "The place where I work in." ?
Which is correct ?
Should I add "in" ?
I have problem with prepostions.

Answer (score 1):

It is, "The place where I work." To include "*in*" in the sentence would require changing it to, "The place in which I work", which is still correct but less idiomatic.

What may help to decide whether you need the preposition as in the question, is to use a variation of the basic sentence, such as answering a question:

> I work in an office.
>   Where I work is in an office.
>   The place where I work is an office.
>   The place where I work is in an office building.

Then the alternative construction including "*in*" starts looking strange:

> Where I work *in* is *in* an office.
>   The place where I work *in* is an office.
>   The place where I work *in* is *in* an office building.

The latter grouping becomes more difficult to say, and often this can be a clue that it is not correct, or at least not idiomatic.